# when i use the gridsplitter to resize the height of a listview the vertical scrollbar is collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to resize the listview which contains many element with GridSplitter, the problem is that when I use the GridSplitter the vertical scrollbar that allows me to see other colones, disappears. i need help to resolve this

```
<Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewDate}" x:Name="DashboardListViewGeneral" Height="350" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Single" Behavior:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True" Behavior:GridViewSort.SortGlyphAscending="/Asset/Pict/arrow_down.png" Behavior:GridViewSort.SortGlyphDescending="/Asset/Pict/arrow_up.png" MaxHeight="Infinity" MinHeight="0">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" x:Name="zzz">
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=NumberGeco}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Id"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=NumSolution}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.Number, Mode=OneWay}" Width="20" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.Number"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Title}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" Width="400" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Title"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Programs}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProgramListString, Mode=OneWay}" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="ProgramListString"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Origin}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RequestOrigin.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="40" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="RequestOrigin.Name"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Type}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RequestType.Name, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='', FallbackValue=''}" Width="40" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="RequestTypeSort"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Responsible}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.CreatorString, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='', FallbackValue=''}" Width="70" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.CreatorString"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Siglum}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.Creator.Department.Name, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='', FallbackValue=''}" Width="70" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.Creator.Department.Name"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Importance}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PriorityFaam.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="40" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="PriorityFaamSort"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Reference}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Reference, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='', FallbackValue=''}" Width="70" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Reference"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Status}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.Statut.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.Statut.Name"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Identifier}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.Identifier, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='', FallbackValue=''}" Width="70" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.Identifier"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ThresholdNRC}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.Complement.ThresholdNrc.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="40" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.Number"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ThresholdRC}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.Complement.ThresholdRc.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="40" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.Number"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=DateReception}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.DateReception, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yy}}" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.DateReception"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=DateObjective}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.DateObjective, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yy}}" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.DateObjective"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=DateTechnicalFile}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.Complement.DateTechnicalReport, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yy}}" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.Complement.DateTechnicalReport"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardCellTemplate}" Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=DateDiffusion}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastSolution.Complement.DateCirculatuion, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yy}}" Behavior:GridViewSort.PropertyName="LastSolution.Complement.DateCirculatuion"/>

                        </GridView>                          
                    </ListView.View>

                    </ListView>


                    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Black" ShowsPreview="True" Height="2" ResizeDirection="Rows" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />




                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <Image Source="/Asset/Pict/excel_logo.png" Width="20" MouseLeftButtonDown="ExportExcelGeneral_Click" Cursor="Hand" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ExportListToExcel}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="ExportExcelGeneral_Click" Cursor="Hand" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <TextBlock   Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <Binding ElementName="DashboardListViewGeneral" Path="Items.Count" StringFormat="{}{0} viewed demands" FallbackValue="nombre de dossiers affichés" Mode="OneWay" />
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>


                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
```